# What does this in Ruby do?

Tags: ruby

I was looking on solution at codewars and found this piece of code.
What does the part "`..?z`" in `Array(char.next..?z)` do?
I know that ".." it is for range ie. `"a".."z"` but idk. what 
 **?z** do.

Comment: `?z` is merely the string `"z"`.

Comment: You awarded the greenie to @Matt after a mere 20 minutes. I have no disagreement with your choice but in future I would encourage you to wait longer (at least a couple of hours, say) before selecting an answer. Quick selections can discourage other answers and imo are discourteous to those still working on answers. There's no rush!

Comment: I recommend bookmarking http://symbolhound.com for this sort of thing.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ok, i will respect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?z` is the same as `'z'`. It is a single character literal string.

From the [Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings):

> There is also a character literal notation to represent single character strings, which syntax is a question mark (?) followed by a single character or escape sequence that corresponds to a single codepoint in the script encoding:
>
> ```
> ?a       #=> "a"
> ?abc     #=> SyntaxError
> ?\n      #=> "\n"
> ?\s      #=> " "
> ?\\      #=> "\\"
> ?\u{41}  #=> "A"
> ?\C-a    #=> "\x01"
> ?\M-a    #=> "\xE1"
> ?\M-\C-a #=> "\x81"
> ?\C-\M-a #=> "\x81", same as above
> ?あ      #=> "あ"
> ```

Comment: This might seem pedantic, but `?z` is the same as `"z"` not `'z'`. For the letter **z** there is no difference, but there is for things like `?\n` and `?\t` (Though your quote states this correctly)

Answer (score 0):

? will convert the given character into string,

```
?z means 'z' 

?a means 'a'

?a..?z means 'a'..'z'
```

Comment: Okay changed now.

Comment: This might seem pedantic, but `?z` means `"z"` not `'z'`. For the letter **z** there is no difference, but there is for things like `?\n` and `?\t`